# Каким способом я могу распарсить xml, получаемый с сервера?

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, resttemplate

Есть xml-данные http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp.
Мне нужно распарсить курс за день и весь список валют за данный курс.
Что мне использовать и с чем работать? Нужно ли использовать SOAP-сервис или можно обойтись только RestTemplate?

Я попытался использовать RestTemplate, но список с запроса пуст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Контроллер:

```
package com.example.converter.controllers;


import com.example.converter.models.Currency;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@RestController
public class RestTemplateController {

private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Value("${application.uri}")
private String url;

@Autowired
public RestTemplateController(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
}



@GetMapping(value = "/get_xml")
public List<Currency> getListCurrency() {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters",headers);
    ResponseEntity<Currency[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            url,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            entity,
            Currency[].class
    );

    return Arrays.asList(Objects.requireNonNull(response.getBody()));
}
```

}

Его настройка:

```
@Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));
        messageConverters.add(converter);
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

        return restTemplate;
    }
```

И модель для записи в БД:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(schema = "public")
@ToString(of = {"id", "numCode", "charCode", "nominal", "name", "value"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "numCode", "charCode", "nominal", "name", "value"})
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Currency implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;
    private Integer numCode;
    private String charCode;
    private Integer nominal;
    private String name;
    private Double value;

}
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization

Comment: Причем тут SOAP? Если вы отправляете HTTP запрос для того, чтобы получить данные, то это RESTful веб-сервис. Не важно в каком формате данные, важно что вы делаете для того, чтобы их получить!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще всего реализовать с помощью Jsoup.

```
    String url = "http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp";
    Document page = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements x = page.select("Name");
    System.out.println(x.eachText());
    Elements y = page.select("Value");
    System.out.println(y.eachText());
```

И любые другие удобные Вам вариации. https://jsoup.org/cookbook/